# What is sin and what is not?

Tags: practical-islam, source-identification, prophet-muhammad, allah, ramadan

I have a question in my mind from many year. I haven't got any perfect answer. In Islam, we have so many restriction that we can't do many thing, and we follow few things told.

For an example we have pray five times Namaz & also we must fast during the month of Ramadan. What I feel doing well is holy deed but what if we don't do then how can it be sin. When we aren't following good thing doesn't mean that we are doing any bad thing. If we are doing good things (like praying) or Just praying 2-3 time Namaz during a whole day then Why would Allah punish us. What I feel that there is a miscommunication happen from generation to generation.

> 1) May be a person from Generation 1 told us that god sent us to the earth. We owe god. We should pray five time Namaz & also we **should** do whole Ramadan fast.
>
> 2) May be a person from Generation 2 told us that god sent us to the earth. We owe god. We must pray five time & also we **must** do whole Ramadan fast.

And now we have considered that everything is must (compulsory) it is not should.

If some people are praying 2-3 time Namaz during the whole day or some people are praying only jumma to jumma. We follow it our own nobody forces us. There are people who follow 20-30 % out of 100% compulsory things but the rest of the things how can it be sin. They are not doing the rest of the things so it shouldn't be sin.

Every human being in the world all are same/equal for god. We some Muslim are at least following things 20-30% but those people who are not Muslim who are Hindu, Sikh, Christian and many more they are not following anything what we are following. Then is really god is going to punish them & god will send them to hell?. Because they are not Muslim & they don't pray Namaz & also don't do fast of Ramadan.

I respect god (Allah). I try to pray as much as possible from my own, but these are my concern. Please provide your view on this with proof if is there any

Comment: "There are people who follow 20-30 % out of 100% compulsory things but the rest of the things how can it be sin. They are not doing the rest of the things so it shouldn't be sin." - i do not understand this.

Answer (score 1):

One question of yours is, Muslims are to do all the obligatory things but non Muslims are not doing any of these so what will happen to them in hereafter. Quran says Allah will judge between them on day of Judgement.

> For every religion We have appointed rites which they perform. So, let
>   the disbelievers not contend with you over the matter but invite them
>   to your Lord. Indeed, you are upon straight guidance.
>
> And if they dispute with you, then say, " Allah is most knowing of
>   what you do.
>
> Allah **will judge between you** on the Day of Resurrection concerning
>   that over which you used to differ." [Quran 22:67-69](http://quran.com/22/66-72)

Allah knows everything about each one of them and he is the Most merciful, he will judge accordingly to all. Muslims are to admonish them and invite them to become followers of final prophet(s.a) but we have no right to judge all of them are in hell fire.

Answer (score 0):

'And I have not created the jinn and mankind except to worship Me' (51:56)

I think this verse alone answers most of your question, eapecially regarding the prayer.

I understand why you may feel that way regarding restrictions and what not, but in reality, islam has placed no restrictions for us. If anything, these so called 'restrictions' are a blessing to us. For example, we are not allowed to eat pork. Why not? First an foremost because Allah SWT has told us in the quran. But behind every ruling in islam there is a wisdom. If you knew the illnesses and diseases that eating pork carried, you wouldnt even think ot it as a restriction (this of course is just an example)

Also dont think of doing good as 'owing god'. Think of this life as a test. You are going to die wether you like it or not. We all are. But what have you done in this life to prepare you for death? After you die there is no going back. You are gone forever, and a that you will take with you are the deeds you did on this earth-good or bad. God has given you will and the power to make decisions, its up to you to use that to your benefit.

I can go on forever but regarding the 5 daily prayers, this is actually an obligatory upon us as muslims, and they are actually a blessing as they were originally 50. Every prayer we pray is worth ten (i dont want to go too much into this, but the story behind it is the journey of israa and miraj, you should look into it its really interesting).

I hope this answer helped, and may Allah SWT guide us all to the right path. Amen

Comment: I agree that every person is going to die. whether he is muslim or any religion. whatever good deed we had that is going to come with us nothing else. but My question is that people who are non muslim what is going to happen with them on the judgement day? we atleast pay namaz & do whatever this are there in our cast then what about others???

Comment: @user13138 its all in the quran. they are given signs and many chances to turn to islam but dont, so they go to hell fire. i know i've just made that sound really harsh, but trust me, if you read the quran you will get a better undertsanding. Dont think that they just live life without chances, as everyone is alive and eveyone will die, so everyone's life is a test-muslim or not

Answer (score 0):

SIN was a term in archery that means to miss the mark.

All mentally sound people know right from wrong. To do wrong when we know right was the correct choice, was to miss the mark, or SIN we had set for our goal. Allah sets the target, we need to follow the path he has shown to us.

Allah knows the hearts and understanding of all of us individually. He reaches us in our own hearts and minds.

You must be called by Allah to find the path, many times Allah calls, when you respond the magic begins within you.

A favorite verse in the Quran is in surah 55! Ar-Rahman. ... FABI AYYI AALAAII RABBIKUMAA TUKAZZIBAAN
Which of these things would you deny you’ll lord?

Once you start to see Allahs miracles in your life, you will relate to him all the good things of your life and on earth.

Answer (score -1):

Any person who fails to adhere to the commands of Allah is liable to be either punished or forgiven and that is for those that die as Muslims.. Those who completely reject Allahs message after receiving and understanding it they will go to hell forever because they knowingly made a choice to reject it. People who try their best to follow Allah's commands they may not follow them perfectly but Allah's mercy is for those people because they didn't reject Allah's message these are believers. All people should read Allah's book the Quran.

Quran 9:68 Allah has promised the hypocrite men and hypocrite women and the disbelievers the fire of Hell, wherein they will abide eternally. It is sufficient for them. And Allah has cursed them, and for them is an enduring punishment.